# Prevent onFocusChanged firing when ScrollView is scrolled

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a problem where I have several TextView objects in my Activity. More than can fit on the screen view so I have placed them inside a ScrollView.

Now each TextView item is placed into a RelativeLayout before placing onto the ScrollView.
Each RelativeLayout object then has onClickListener and onFocusChangedListeners assigned.
Each Listener implements a method that pops up a dialog to enable the user to edit the value stored by the TextView.

The problem that is occuring is that when the screen is scrolled the onFocusChangedListener event is fired causing the dialog to appear for several items at a time.

Is it possible to detect if the Scrollview is scrolling and prevent the onFocusedChanged event firing?

I can post code if required but its quite large as the items added to the page are done so dynamically. This also means there is no xml for the layout.

I looked at using the ScrollView onTouchListener to add a flag ignoreFocusChange but it appears this would not work as the event was hit sveral times for one swipe/fling on the screen.

Please help

Regards,

Iain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time on this I found that the best solution for me was to remove the onFocusChangedListener and replace it with onTouchListener

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Unfortunately, I can't remove the onFocusChangedListener or replace it. I need to find a way of really prevent onFoncusChanged firing. It doesn't happen on 4.x version, only on 2.3.6.